# swift class in Objective-C: unknown receiver

Tags: objective-c, swift

I wrote a class in a swift-file:

```
class UtilityMethods {
    class func userId() -> Integer {        
        ...
    }

    class func setUserId(userId : Int) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm importing the -swift.h-header which compiles fine, but I can't use

```
[UtilityMethods userId];
```

in my Objective-C code:

`Unknown receiver 'UtilityMethods'; did you mean 'UtilMethods'?`

`UtilMethods`is an Objective-C class I'd like to replace. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
With the help of Lance, the class is now recognized, but the getter method isn't, unfortunately, the header files looks like the following:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC15...14UtilityMethods")
@interface UtilityMethods : NSObject
+ (void)setUserId:(NSInteger)userId;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Why is the getter missing?

Comment: class func userId() -> Integer should be Int, not Integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a Swift class available to Objective C you have two options:

Option 1: Subclass NSObject (or some other Objective C class)

```
class UtilityMethods : NSObject {
    class func userId() -> Int {
        ...
    }

    class func setUserId(userId: Int) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Option 2: Add the `@objc` attribute to your class telling the Swift compiler to make an Objective C object that uses dynamic dispatch rather than static dispatch for method calls

```
@objc class UtilityMethods {
    class func userId() -> Int {
        ...
    }

    class func setUserId(userId: Int) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was doing @objc correctly, but in changing from my old Objective-C .h file to my new swift file, I had accidentally lost the Target Membership of the new file, so it wasn't being included in the build.